# Ionic2 Social Sharing Facebook not working

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, ionic2

So the problem is that the specified `message` is not in the facebook modal sharing window, it's empty doesn't have any text.

```
  import {SocialSharing} from 'ionic-native';
  ...
  shareFb(message?: string){
    SocialSharing.shareViaFacebook(message,null,null).then(()=>{
        //Success
      },
      ()=>{
        //cancel      
      });
    }


<ion-icon name="logo-facebook" 
 class="share-facebook" (click)="shareFb(message.description)">
 </ion-icon>  <ion-icon ios="logo-twitter" md="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also struggled with this finally to find out - **Sharing a message on Facebook is not possible** (as of today).

It is mentioned in the `SocialSharing` plugin documentation at this [part](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#4a-usage-on-ios-and-android).

[This](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/332619626816423/) is an issue with the facebook API. Here they have mentioned:

> This issue is going to be closed by design because our API does not support pre-filling the message for users as seen in our Policy Documentation here

Basically, to sum up, it is not in there policy to allow this. Hope this helps.